# paste.urlparser.staticurlparser won't find right directory

Tags: url, python-2.7, url-routing, wsgi

I'm (trying) using staticurlparser in dev to serve static files, using cascade to switch between this an another app.  But I can't seem to get the syntax right.

My dev server is an amazon ec2 instance that I serve everything over the web in port 8080.

the directory I need to serve is located at home/ubuntu/appdir/static.

This has been my most recent attempt:

```
 staticdir = StaticURLParser('static',os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'/appdir/static'))
```

My understanding of it was that if I go to ec2-num-.../static/file.txt, staticdir would find file.txt in /home/ubuntu/appdir/static
But staticdir comes up as:

```
<StaticURLParser '/home/ubuntu/static'>
```

instead of the directory above.

as I said before I'm using cascade:

```
webb_app = Cascade([staticdir,otherapp])
```

another problem I may be having is I'm not using the full ec2 server url but I don't know yet.  I'm hoping someone more practiced in paste can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out and thought I'd put it up here for anyone else who's looking in the future.

StaticURLParser takes the first argument and directs requests to it according to two things: It starts at the current working directory if not told otherwise.
And also a leading slash makes a big difference i.e. using the leading "/" makes StaticURLParser treat the argument as the full path.  "/static" searches for "/static".  It's likely not what you are looking for so use "static" instead.

Other than that, things are embarrassingly simple.  If your static directory is at "static"  and you have a javascript file in "static/js":
direct yourself to http://yourhost.com/js/file.js.  Leave out the "static" portion.  That was my problem all along.